# How to redirect to login page after signout button is pressed in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Here i am using firebase phone authentication, so whenever i click sigout button it gets signed out from firebase instance but it doesn't redirect to the login page.

Here is the code for the sigout button

```
  return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Signout'),
              onPressed: () {
                AuthService().signOut();
              },
            )
        )
    );
```

Here is the code for AuthService

```
  class AuthService {

  handleAuth() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return HomeScreen();
          } else {
            return LoginPage();
          }
        });
  }

  //Sign out
  signOut() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  //SignIn
  signIn(AuthCredential authCreds) {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCreds);
  }

  signInWithOTP(smsCode, verId) {
    AuthCredential authCreds = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verId, smsCode: smsCode);
    signIn(authCreds);
  }
}
```

How do i redirect it to the login page when signout button is pressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call your login screen  and clear out all the previous paths

you can use below shown code

it  will clear all the paths and your history and launch new `LoginScreen`

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
    new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            new LoginScreen()),
    (route) => false);
```